# Why I cannot make increment on the power in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to learn about Javascript. The problem I am facing currently is that I wish to increase the power to the base of 5 eventually until the answer capped at 200.

This is the output I expect:

```
5 
25 
125
```

However, the output I gotten is only:

```
5
25
```

I cant seem to get 125 even-though the cap is at 200.

Here is the code I had written:

```js
let y = 5;
let z = "";

for (let x = 1; z <= 200; z = (y **= (x++))) {
  console.log(z);
}
```

Comment: In a `for (a; b; c) d` loop, the `c` is executed **after** the `d`.

Comment: do you mind if i ask which one is (a; b; c) d for my code?

Comment: isn't it obvious? `a;` = `let x = 1;` `b;` = `z <= 200;` ... do you need the other two explained as well?

Comment: ohh, I got the structure now. Thanks for the help. :)